# Is there a way to subfacet a table which has been already “faceted”?

Tags: google-refine

I have a table on which I'm applying a customized facet in order to find duplicates (on a column). Now I'd like to apply a new facet (on another column) on the table with the facet.

Is that possible? It seems that it can be used only one facet per time, and not combined ones together.

Cheers,

elisa

Answer (score 1):

Facets can be combined on the same column or on multiple one to narrow down your data. 
When you facet on two different column in the same time, result are a combination of: facet 1 AND facet 2. So in you case it will be within your duplicate records, records that match the criteria of your second facet.

You can also combine facet within the same column to create. You can read more about faceting here: http://googlerefine.blogspot.ca/2011/09/use-google-refine-to-navigate-data.html